# How do I make a certified copy of a website before it can be changed?

Tags: website

Assume I am in dispute with an insurance company, who is refusing, via email correspondence, to honour terms currently displayed prominently on their website. How can I make a "certified" copy of said website, before they have the opportunity to change it? I wish to be able to show that the website, at a certain date (today), contained certain pieces of text, but of course knowing that I am in dispute with them they may change their website content at any time which would cause me to  lose said proof.

Said copy would have to be verifiable through a third party, because it's otherwise their word against mine (were I simply to take screenshots).

Is there an online service for this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the URL in archive.org, and if it's there you could potentially use that. However, the insurance company can request deletion from archive.org.